# Best way to rotate html on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to be able to rotate between five distinct pieces of html in my webpage every 8 seconds.

What's the best way to do this? JQuery or native JS is fine.

Comment: what's the content? how would you want to rotate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely a lot of plugins for that.

But here's some basic structure you could use if you want to do it yourself:

```
// assuming all your divs have the class `rotating-content`:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = $('.rotating-content').hide();
    var curr_div = divs.first().show();        

    function nextcontent() {
        // hide current div, then move the next one or the first div, and show it
        curr_div = curr_div.hide().next().add(divs.first()).first().show();
        setTimeout(nextcontent, 5000); // 5 seconds
    }
    setTimeout(nextcontent, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a slideshow? You can use [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin from malsup,

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/zLekb/ (none of this extra stuff is necessary, this is just an example I've been recycling)

if you want it to change every 8 seconds change `timeout` to 8000 (it's measured in milliseconds)